# find average variance across columns & average of variance across rows in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the data as follows:-

```
  a  b   c   d
  5  6   32  12
  9  8   16  23
  15 8   14  20
```

I want to check the variance of each column and then have 1 variance for each column. Then I would like to get average of variance across columns & finally reach one number for this entire dataset.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want [`var`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html) and [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html)?

```
df.var().mean()
```

output: `39.083333333333336`

intermediate:

```
df.var()

a    25.333333
b     1.333333
c    97.333333
d    32.333333
dtype: float64
```

*NB. by default, `var` used 1 degree of freedom (`ddof=1`) to compute the variance. Id you want 0, use `df.var(ddof=0)`.*